# Dragging an object out of its container using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I wish to be able to drag an HTML object out of its container.

I manage to do so. However, when I drag it out (by appending it to `body`), the draggable object moves to the top left corner of the page.

This might be more easy to explain if I show you an example I made in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rq3Ta/3/

I have objects that have a content. The content of an object may be an object itself.
Objects are draggable by using the little dark squares with class `drag-from-here`. When I move an object out of its container I'd like it to stay at the same place, with my cursor still on the `drag-from-here` box.

I might not be approaching this correctly. I attempted to manually set the `top` and `left` style properties after appending the object to body, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

The draggable widget also seems to have an `appendTo` option but I couldn't get it to work the way I expected it to.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremelly *hacky*, but managed to solve the problem.
While changing the `top` and `left` properties after appending the element to `body` didn't seem to have any effect, changing the `margin-top` and `margin-left` did.

When the dragging stops I had to remove the added margins.
Here is the JSFiddle with the solution I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/Rq3Ta/6/

Comment: I find this solution very ugly and it would need some tweaking to deal with elements that already had a margin, therefore I'd still like to see the proper way of doing this.